# Receive an email when Firebase Realtime DB gets new data from Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I want to receive an email when my Firebase Realtime database gets new data (user phone).
Data are sent to Firebase with Dialogflow inline editor.

I found that I have to use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and update my package.json with [depedencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398663/use-nodemailer-in-dialogflow).

I found an [example but it sends the email to the user](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/email-confirmation/functions/index.js).

I didn't succeed to adapt it to send me an email (not to the user) when he fills a new data with Firebase function (with onWrite()).

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

In the [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/email-confirmation/functions/index.js) you reference, lines 42 - 45 should allow you to change the recipient's email address:

```
  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Spammy Corp." <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: val.email,
  };
```

What happens when you pass in your own email as a string in the `mailOptions.to` object?