# How do I send an email with Dialoflow for Google actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have looked all over to find a solution to run an intent that sends an email but cannot find any solutions. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**nodemailer**](https://nodemailer.com/about/) in your dialogflow webhook fulfillment intent to send emails.

Make sure to enable less secure apps [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) to use gmail to send emails.

Code for sending emails using nodemailer from your intent :

```
app.intent('sendMail', (conv, params) => {

      const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
          pass: 'yourPassword'
        }
      });

      var mailOptions = {
        from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
        to: email, //receiver email 
        subject: 'Mail subject',
        text: 'mail body'
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
      });

});
```

If you are using inline editor follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398663/use-nodemailer-in-dialogflow) for assistance.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'd update that answer to make sure it returns a Promise. {:

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific API for sending an email from an Action or through Dialogflow.

However, if your Intent has fulfillment turned on, you can call any API or library from that intent handler in your webhook.